# How to add event handling in BootStrap menu/dropdown menu

Tags: bootstrap-5

I am building a Single page Application in JavaScript.  I am following this example to use BootStrap 5 menu and dropdown menu.

How can I add code to handle when user select a menu and an item in the drop down menu?
Here is the example of my menu bar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Dropdown
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a user selects a dropdown item, a click event is triggered.

Therefore, you can add an event listener to all `dropdown-item` of `dropdown-menu`, in order to add your code for handling.

```js
const dropdownItems = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-menu .dropdown-item")

dropdownItems.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    // your code here
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks. But the 'dropdown' in bootstrap is using `<ul><li>` not `<select>`

Comment: You're right! I edited my answer.